# How to Timeout After Calling Await on an async function in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, web3js

I have an async function `web3.eth.net.isListening()` that causes the following statement to be stuck forever if there is an error:

```
await web3.eth.net.isListening()
```

How can we let the above `await` statement timeout after 10 seconds, and do a `console.log` to show that an error has occurred?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to provide a second Promise that is tied to a timeout.

```
await Promise.race([
    web3.eth.net.isListening(),
    new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('Timed out');
            resolve();
        }, 10000);
    }),
]);
```

Comment: Good idea to `.race`, but I would reject in your timeout.